# Automatically BCC in Outlook Office 365 or Outlook Desktop on Mac or PC

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, applescript, bcc

I am trying to automatically populate the bcc field with an email address in order to get emails to flow through to Pipedrive CRM. I am wondering how I can run a script to make this populate since there currently is not any functionality in Outlook to do this.

I tried using an Applescript but it is not working. I need it to populate the bcc field when I reply to a message AND when I create a New message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install this plugin:
[Auto BCC/CC plug-in](https://www.ablebits.com/outlook-blind-carbon-copy-bcc-email-addins/index.php)

**Note:**

Payware, but has *"Unconditional 60-days money-back guarantee"*

Comment: Hey Behzad, so my company actually restricts downloading plug-ins. So it has to be a way where I don't have to rely on those.

Comment: Hey, there is a built-in option for this. check out this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-add-auto-bcc-to-all-user-accounts/89dda0d8-de33-412d-9e3d-e4fd76f97c2a

Comment: Certainly you can set a BCC address via rules. One disadvantage: while creating a new message/replying you don't see the BCC field populated.

Comment: @VictorIvanidze - could you clarify the bcc address via rules? So when a draft of an email is created there is a rule where it automatically bcc's the email address in the rule? I searched high and low for something like that an couldn't find it. The address I want to BCC is different than the sender address too

Comment: @CaitlinFerson - follow the behzad's link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-add-auto-bcc-to-all-user-accounts/89dda0d8-de33-412d-9e3d-e4fd76f97c2a?auth=1

Comment: Note, the link that can _"set a BCC address via rules"_ is done via EAC, i.e., the "Exchange Admin Center" in the backend.